# Autocomplete feature shows [Object object]

Tags: reactjs, rest

i am trying to implement auto complete feature in react JS.

it shows the autocomplete box, but shows [Object Object] for some reason, I have no idea why. I want it to show the email in the search box so as to implement autocomplete feature.

I would like to share my source code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Home.css'


const SearchRepo = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState([]);

const onChangeHandler = (text) =>{
    //setSeachUser(e.target.value);
    let matches = []
    if(text.length > 0){
        matches = users.filter(user =>{
            const regex = new RegExp(`${text}`,"gi");
            return user.email.match(regex);
        })
    } 
    setSuggestions(matches);
    setText(text);
}

useEffect(()=>{
    const loadUsers = async()=>{
        const response = await axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users');
        setUsers(response.data.data);
    }
    loadUsers();
},[])


    return (
        <div align="center">
            <table border="0" width="100%" height="212px">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#C0C0C0" height="55px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>
                        <font face="Berlin Sans FB" color="#333333">Github Repo Search</font></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div align="center">
                            <table border="0" width="100%" className="SearchTable">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="      Enter github repo ID / username" name="T1" size="88" value={text} onChange={e =>onChangeHandler(e.target.value)} className="inputArea" />
                                    {suggestions && suggestions.map((suggestion,i)=>{
                                        <div key={i}>{suggestion.email}</div>
                                    })}
                                </div>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div align="center">
                            <table border="0" width="100%" className="reposresultsTable">
                                <div align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>
                                            <font face="Verdana" size="2" className="labeltxt"><h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Repos</h3></font></b>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </div>

                                <div align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="23">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>
                                            <font face="Verdana" size="2">
                                                <a href="https://test-restapi2.herokuapp.com/employees/">
                                                    mmmmmmmm</a></font></b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </div>

                            </table>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SearchRepo;
```

why would it be showing that Object rather than the email? Please is there something i am not getting rightly?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, the issue was with a Curly brace. I have been able to resolve it. Thanks everyone.

Changing from this :

```
<div align="center">
    <input type="text" placeholder="      Enter github repo ID / username" name="T1" size="88" value={text} onChange={e =>onChangeHandler(e.target.value)} className="inputArea" />
    {suggestions && suggestions.map((suggestion,i)=>{
        <div key={i}>{suggestion.email}</div>
    })}
</div>
```

to this

```
<div align="center">
    <input type="text" placeholder="      Enter github repo ID / username" name="T1" size="88" value={text} onChange={e =>onChangeHandler(e.target.value)} className="inputArea" />
    {suggestions && suggestions.map((suggestion,i)=>
        <div key={i}>{suggestion.email}</div>
    )}
</div>
```